# I am getting Problem while Scraping Span class with ImportXML

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to get a Website scraped and while trying the below `importxml` function I am not getting the result. Please let me know what I am missing. The function I'm using is as following:

```
=IMPORTXML(https://www.bjs.com/product/keter-easy-grow-elevated-garden-bed/287699,"//span[@class='price-display green-Price']")
```

Answer (score 0):

#### **the reason is denied access (eg. site is not public/visible for Google Sheets):**

[image: 0]